# C++ casting a derived subclass into another derived subclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class

So what I'm trying to achieve here is casting a derived subclass into another subclass derived from the same subclass. This far it's looking like it's not possible to actually be done but I'm still believing.

My example code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void printFunction() = 0;
};

class printOne : public BaseClass
{
public:
    void printFunction() override
    {
        std::cout << "One\n";
    }
};

class printTwo : public BaseClass
{
public:
    void printFunction() override
    {
        std::cout << "Two\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<BaseClass *> baseClassVector;

    printOne * one = new printOne;
    baseClassVector.push_back(one);

    printTwo * two = new printTwo;
    baseClassVector.push_back(two);

}
```

So what i want to actually do here with this vector is that I want to change the "one" object on index zero, to a "two" object. Now this can be done through the code

```
delete baseClassVector[0];

printTwo * two = new printTwo;
baseClassVector[0] = two;
```

However as far as I know, this is extremely costly, especially if it has to be done at runtime. I was wondering if there's another way to go about doing this or if the costs are worth it compared to other alternatives.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your class hierarchies can afford it, you may use a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which is also known as _Static Polymorphism_. There won't be any runtime overhead, but restrictions in the way how you can build class hierarchies as mentioned. _"However as far as I know, this is extremely costly ..."_ Maybe less than you think it is. Measure, try to eliminate bottlenecks where the dynamic casts are done, then measure again.

Comment: `struct base {}` will come in handy

Comment: Note that for `delete baseClassVector[0]` to work properly, `BaseClass` must have a virtual destructor. If you delete an object of a derived type through a pointer to a base type and that base type does not have a virtual destructor, the behavior is undefined. Your example it probably “works” just fine. That’s an insidious property of undefined behavior: your code sometimes doesn’t show any symptoms, so you don’t notice the problem. Then you make a small change and things start to blow up.

Comment: It is technically possible to cast the pointers.    The "cost" of this approach may be unacceptable - subsequent usage of the object (pointed to by the pointer) gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The vector of pointers to base type suggests true dynamic polymorphism is expected here.

Answer (score 3):

With the simplified example in the question, use a `std::variant` which is simpler and just avoid the base class altogether:

```
class printOne
{
public:
    void printFunction() const
    {
        std::cout << "One\n";
    }
};

class printTwo
{
public:
    void printFunction() const
    {
        std::cout << "Two\n";
    }
};

using printEither = std::variant<printOne, printTwo>;

void printFunction(const printEither& e)
{
    std::visit([](auto& p) { p.printFunction(); }, e);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<printEither> eitherVector;

    printOne one;
    eitherVector.push_back(one);

    printTwo two;
    eitherVector.push_back(two);

    eitherVector[0] = two;

    for (auto& e: eitherVector)
        printFunction(e);
}
```

Re-using an allocation for effectively unrelated types in C++ is a pain to write correctly. It is easier and preferable to incur an allocation.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible to "rebuild" an object in place as a different type, though the following should be taken as just a proof of concept, not a recommendation for design or practice. First price to pay is giving up the convenience of `new/delete` for manually managed placement new and explicit destructors used with `malloc/free`.

```
const size_t sz = max(sizeof(printOne), sizeof(printTwo));

BaseClass *either = (BaseClass *)malloc(sz);       // allocate memory for objects

new(either) printOne();                            // construct printOne object
printOne *one = dynamic_cast<printOne *>(either);  // ... use printOne object
one->~printOne();                                  // destruct printOne object

new(either) printTwo();                            // construct printTwo object
printTwo *two = dynamic_cast<printTwo *>(either);  // ... use printTwo object
two->~printTwo();                                  // destruct printTwo object

free(either);                                      // free memory used by objects
```

Comment: And this is approximately what `std::variant` does for you besides the scenes, at least as a start.

Comment: @aschepler To some extent, yes, though in OP's use case that would not be too different from the code they proposed and asked for alternatives - which I understood to mean alternatives that avoid (re)allocations when types change.